# useEffect efficiency in Star Wars API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I need some help with me current project making in React. I'am making a star-wars-app for my job interview and I stucked on a one problem.
Fetch efficiency.

I'am fetching this data, and then fetching some more because of the url's in the first fetched data, and everything fetches good, but first i have the 'url's' seeing in the table and then it changes into correct data.

I want to set the 'fetched' state to true when everything is rendered correctly but I don't know how to do it.

```
    const api = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/`;
    const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
    const [speciesOptions, setSpeciesOptions] = useState([]);
    const [homeworldOptions, setHomeworldOptions] = useState([]);
    const [fetched, setFetched] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchedTimeout = () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setFetched(true);
            }, 2000);
        };

        const fetchArray = (array, arrName) => {
            for (let elem of array) {
                fetch(elem).then((response) =>
                    response.json().then((data) => {
                        array.shift();
                        array.push(data.name);
                    })
                );
            }
            if (arrName === "species") {
                if (!array.length) {
                    array.push("Unspecified");
                }
            }
        };

        async function fetchOtherData(characters) {
            await characters.forEach((character) => {
                const homeworld = character.homeworld;
                const vehicles = character.vehicles;
                const starships = character.starships;
                const species = character.species;

                fetch(homeworld).then((response) =>
                    response.json().then((data) =>
                        setCharacters((prevData) =>
                            prevData.map((prevCharacter) =>
                                prevCharacter.homeworld === homeworld
                                    ? {
                                            ...prevCharacter,
                                            homeworld: data.name,
                                      }
                                    : prevCharacter
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );

                fetchArray(vehicles);
                fetchArray(starships);
                fetchArray(species, "species");
            });
            await setCharacters(characters);
            await fetchedTimeout();
        }

        const fetchAllCharacters = (allCharacters, data) => {
            if (data.next) {
                fetch(data.next)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        allCharacters.push(...data.results);
                        fetchAllCharacters(allCharacters, data);
                    });
            }
            if (!data.next) {
                fetchOtherData(allCharacters);
            }
        };

        async function fetchApi() {
            const allCharacters = [];
            await fetch(api)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    allCharacters.push(...data.results);
                    fetchAllCharacters(allCharacters, data);
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }

        const setSpeciesFiltering = () => {
            const speciesFiltering = [];

            for (let character of characters) {
                const characterSpecies = character.species.join();
                const foundSpecies = speciesFiltering.indexOf(characterSpecies);
                if (foundSpecies === -1) {
                    speciesFiltering.push(characterSpecies);
                }
            }
            const speciesOptions = speciesFiltering.map((species) => (
                <option value={species}>{species}</option>
            ));

            setSpeciesOptions(speciesOptions);
        };

        const setHomeworldFiltering = () => {
            const homeworldFiltering = [];

            for (let character of characters) {
                const characterHomeworld = character.homeworld;
                const foundSpecies =
                    homeworldFiltering.indexOf(characterHomeworld);
                if (foundSpecies === -1) {
                    homeworldFiltering.push(characterHomeworld);
                }
            }
            const homeworldOptions = homeworldFiltering.map((homeworld) => (
                <option value={homeworld}>{homeworld}</option>
            ));

            setHomeworldOptions(homeworldOptions);
        };
        fetchApi();
        setSpeciesFiltering();
        setHomeworldFiltering();
    }, []);
```

I will appreciate your response.

Okay, after all the comments (thanks for that!) i changed the code to something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchOtherData = (characters) => {
            const charactersWithAllData = [];
            characters.forEach((character) => {
                const homeworld = character.homeworld;
                const species = character.species;
                const vehicles = character.vehicles;
                const starships = character.starships;
                let urls = [homeworld, ...species, ...vehicles, ...starships];

                Promise.all(
                    urls.map((url) => {
                        if (url.length) {
                            fetch(url)
                                .then((response) => response.json())
                                .then((data) => {
                                    if (url.search("species") > 0) {
                                        character.species = data.name;
                                    }
                                    if (url.search("planets") > 0) {
                                        character.homeworld = data.name;
                                    }
                                    if (url.search("vehicles") > 0) {
                                        character.vehicles.shift();
                                        character.vehicles.push(data.name);
                                    }
                                    if (url.search("starships") > 0) {
                                        character.starships.shift();
                                        character.starships.push(data.name);
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch((err) => console.error(err));
                        }
                        if (!url.length) {
                            if (url.search("species")) {
                                character.species = "Unspecified";
                            }
                            if (url.search("vehicles")) {
                                character.vehicles = "";
                            }
                            if (url.search("starships")) {
                                character.starships = "";
                            }
                        }
                    })
                ).then(charactersWithAllData.push(character));
            });
            return charactersWithAllData;
        };

        const fetchApi = () => {
            const characters = [];
            Promise.all(
                [api].map((api) =>
                    fetch(api)
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((data) => characters.push(...data.results))
                        .then((data) => {
                            setCharacters(fetchOtherData(characters));
                        })
                )
            );
        };
        fetchApi();
    }, []);
```

In what point do i have to set the 'characters' state ? Because in the situation above the data first shows on the screen, and then the state is set.

Comment: `Promise.all` might be helpful.

Comment: You could map all the fetch requests to an array of Promises and `Promise.all` them. Don't mix `async/await` with promise-chains. `Array.prototype.forEach` is synchronous so you can't `await` it. The `fetchArray` function appears to mutate the array passed to it. Also, you shouldn't store JSX in state, i.e. the species and home world options. Store the data and render the options out with rendering the UI.

Comment: What Drew said, but I would also advise to break out your `useEffect` hooks to do just ONE thing each, and have other `useEffect` hooks with appropriate dependencies on them. It is considered perfectly acceptable practice to have 10 independent hooks, all doing one thing, rather than 1 giant hook doing ten things.

Comment: All of this was quite helpfull, thanks! I have done it the best i could and understood. Could you also take a look on another problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299486/setstate-in-multiple-fetch-requests

Answer (score 0):

As other comments say, using `Promise.all` and refactoroing your `useEffect` is best solution for this.

But this might be helpful if you don't want to change a lot.

(but still consider refactor your hook)

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(0);
const isLoading = loading > 0;

// replace your fetches with below:
const myFetch = async (path) => {
  try {
    setLoading(loading => loading + 1);
    return await fetch(path);
  } finally {
    setLoading(loading => loading - 1);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  // do your stuffs
}, []);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)` and `setIsLoading(true|false)` be simpler and more intuitive? Also, if `loading` is a number you could use the fact that non-zero values are truthy while `0` is falsey, i.e. `!!loading`.

Comment: @DrewReese because, he wants to perform multiple fetches at once.

Comment: All of this was quite helpfull, thanks! I have done it the best i could and understood. Could you also take a look on another problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299486/setstate-in-multiple-fetch-requests