# setState in multiple fetch requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, setstate

I'am doing the StarWars API task for the job interview.

my code look like that and I don't know in what place the **setCharacters** hook should be.
First the page is rendered and then the state is set.
I need the page to be rendered when all the fetches are done.

To try to be more efficient i changed the previous fetches into Promise.all() but right now I'am stuck with the **setCharacters** placement.
The previous topic can be seen here [useEffect efficiency in Star Wars API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69287414/useeffect-efficiency-in-star-wars-api)

```
const api = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/`;
    const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
    const [fetched, setFetched] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchOtherData = (characters) => {
            const charactersWithAllData = [];
            characters.forEach((character) => {
                const homeworld = character.homeworld;
                const species = character.species;
                const vehicles = character.vehicles;
                const starships = character.starships;
                let urls = [homeworld, ...species, ...vehicles, ...starships];

                Promise.all(
                    urls.map((url) => {
                        if (url.length) {
                            fetch(url)
                                .then((response) => response.json())
                                .then((data) => {
                                    if (url.search("species") > 0) {
                                        character.species = data.name;
                                    }
                                    if (url.search("planets") > 0) {
                                        character.homeworld = data.name;
                                    }
                                    if (url.search("vehicles") > 0) {
                                        character.vehicles.shift();
                                        character.vehicles.push(data.name);
                                    }
                                    if (url.search("starships") > 0) {
                                        character.starships.shift();
                                        character.starships.push(data.name);
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch((err) => console.error(err));
                        }
                        if (!url.length) {
                            if (url.search("species")) {
                                character.species = "Unspecified";
                            }
                            if (url.search("vehicles")) {
                                character.vehicles = "";
                            }
                            if (url.search("starships")) {
                                character.starships = "";
                            }
                        }
                    })
                ).then(charactersWithAllData.push(character));
            });
            setCharacters(charactersWithAllData);
        };

        const fetchApi = () => {
            const characters = [];
            Promise.all(
                [api].map((api) =>
                    fetch(api)
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((data) => characters.push(...data.results))
                        .then((data) => fetchOtherData(characters))
                        .then(setFetched(true))
                )
            );
        };
        fetchApi();
    }, []);
```

Thanks for all the of the possible replies.

Comment: Can you share the project on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: https://nyonw.csb.app/

Comment: Has an answer here helped address or resolve your quesiton/issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loading state, which by default is set to true. After you finish fetching the data from the api you can set loading to false and then render the page.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrdersData = Promise.all().then((data) => {
        //Fetch all data
        .....
        //Render page after loading is false
        setLoading(false);
    }).catch()
}, [])
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand how to implement this into my code.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Found a few issues:

1. **Primary Issue:** The `fetchApi` function's `Promise.all` chain was immediately invoking `setFetched(true)` instead of waiting for the chain's `thenable` to invoke it. This is why you are seeing the empty table before the data has been fetched and processed.

   ```
   const fetchApi = () => {
     const characters = [];
     Promise.all(
       [api].map((api) =>
         fetch(api)
           .then((response) => response.json())
           .then((data) => characters.push(...data.results))
           .then((data) => fetchOtherData(characters))
           .then(setFetched(true)) // <-- immediately invoked
       )
     );
   };
   ```
2. `fetchOtherData` function is also synchronous and doesn't return a Promise so the outer Promise-chain in `fetchApi` doesn't wait for the processing to complete, this is why you still see URL strings instead of the resolved values from the `fetch`.

## Solution

Fix the Promise chain in `fetchApi` to be invoked in the `.then` callback. Rework the logic in `fetchOtherData` to wait for the additional `fetch` requests to resolve.

Here's my suggested solution:

```
const api = `https://swapi.dev/api/people/`;

function App() {
  const basicClassName = "starWarsApi";
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [fetched, setFetched] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOtherData = async (characters) => {
      const characterReqs = characters.map(async (character) => {
        const { homeworld, species, starships, vehicles } = character;
        const urls = [homeworld, ...species, ...vehicles, ...starships];

        // Make shallow copy to mutate
        const characterWithAllData = { ...character };

        const urlReqs = urls.map(async (url) => {
          if (url.length) {
            try {
              const response = await fetch(url);
              const { name } = await response.json();
              if (url.includes("species")) {
                characterWithAllData.species = name;
              }
              if (url.includes("planets")) {
                characterWithAllData.homeworld = name;
              }
              if (url.includes("vehicles")) {
                characterWithAllData.vehicles.shift();
                characterWithAllData.vehicles.push(name);
              }
              if (url.includes("starships")) {
                characterWithAllData.starships.shift();
                characterWithAllData.starships.push(name);
              }
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(err);
            }
          } else {
            if (url.includes("species")) {
              characterWithAllData.species = "Unspecified";
            }
            if (url.includes("vehicles")) {
              characterWithAllData.vehicles = "";
            }
            if (url.includes("starships")) {
              characterWithAllData.starships = "";
            }
          }
        });

        await Promise.all(urlReqs); // <-- wait for mutations/updates
        return characterWithAllData;
      });

      return Promise.all(characterReqs);
    };

    const fetchApi = () => {
      Promise.all(
        [api].map((api) =>
          fetch(api)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => fetchOtherData(data.results))
            .then((charactersWithAllData) => {
              setCharacters(charactersWithAllData);
              setFetched(true);
            })
        )
      );
    };
    fetchApi();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={basicClassName}>
      {fetched && (
        <>
          <h1 className={`${basicClassName}__heading`}>Characters</h1>
          <div className={`${basicClassName}__inputsAndBtnsSection`}>
            <FilteringSection
              basicClassName={`${basicClassName}__inputsAndBtnsSection`}
            />
            <ButtonsSection
              basicClassName={`${basicClassName}__inputsAndBtnsSection`}
            />
          </div>
          <CharactersTable characters={characters} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit setstate-in-multiple-fetch-requests]

[image]